# Convertir path de Windows a path de Linux

Tags: bash, batch

Estoy usando `.bat` y `.sh` desde Windows con CMD y Git Bash respectivamente.

El problema es que necesito convertir un path con formato Windows `C:\Desktop\install-new-cashier` a formato UNIX para ser leído desde el `.sh` que ejecuto en Git Bash como el siguiente `/C/Desktop/install-new-cashier`; alguna manera de realizarlo?

Comment: De donde recibir el path? Es de command line? O esta codificado en archivo .sh?

Comment: Cambiar la `C` por `c`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependerá mayormente del entorno, si `bash` es ejecutado en un entorno *msys* o *cygwin* entonces hay un progamada en *PATH* con el nombre `cygpath` , en *msys* cygpath es un archivo .bash que dependiendo la versión puede ser realmente muy simple dando origen a errores (por ejemplo si la ruta no existe), no obstante ignorando los posibles errores, la forma de hacerlo es de la siguiente manera

```
$ cygpath C:\\Users\\usuario\\Desktop\\\install-new-cashier
  /c/Users/usuario/Desktop/install-new-cashier
```

Proceso inverso, almacenado como variable:

```
$  variable=$(cygpath -w /c/Users/usuario/Desktop/install-new-cashier)
$  echo $variable
   C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\install-new-cashier
```

Puedes guiarte en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015348/msys-path-conversion-or-cygpath-for-msys#answer-12063651), o consultar directamente la documentación de tu proveedor de bash

Answer (score 0):

Prueba usando rutas relativas. Si ejecutas el comando desde `Desktop` debería funcionar.

Por ejemplo, si ya estás en `Desktop`:

```
git add ./install-new-cashier/
```

debería funcionar en el Git de Windows y en cualquier sistema operativo tipo *nix.